# How to use Entity Framework to query a table having dynamic columns?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a table named `Tags` in which a new column is added when a user creates a tag (name of the column will be the tag name that the user gave). Also, the column is renamed when a user edits a tag name.

I know there is a design flaw in my application. But just wondering how are we supposed to create a model for such a table? Is there any way I could perform CRUD operation in such table using Entity Framework?

Comment: I think there is some design flaw if you are adding column for each entry.

Comment: Why not do a one column table and add a new record for each tag? Then you won’t run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except it is a very strange design the solution is quite simple - just execute raw SQL query, and do the manual mapping. Example query:

```
    string studentName = ctx.Database
           .SqlQuery<string>("Select tag1 from Posts where postId=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", 1))
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

All CRUD operations you can handle with raw queries.

Comment: I did try this. It's working. I suppose it's the only easy way out.